# Double quotes in arguments are ignored by ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, cmd, talend, processstartinfo

The following command works when entered in cmd :

```
"C:\Program Files\Scripts_Talend\SynchroExo_run.bat" --context_param FileCode=ABCD --context_param FilePath="//networkname/Folder/file.xls" --context_param ReportFilePath=""
```

But it doesn't work when I execute it with ProcessStartInfo :

```
ProcessStartInfo lTalendScriptInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + lCommand)
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    };
Process lTalendScriptProcess = Process.Start(lTalendScriptInfo);
```

**lCommand** being the same command string as shown just before. Quotes are correctly escaped thanks to \.

With ProcessStartInfo, the error is : **'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file**
As if the double quote was ignored and the part following the first space was as argument.

Are there any differences of interpretation between cmd and ProcessStartInfo ?

Comment: Quotes aren't ignored. They simply aren't there. Your string doesn't *contain* any quotes. The call is wrong anyway - you *don't* need to call `cmd.exe` to run any executable, even if it's a batch file. Just use `new ProcessStartInfo("C:\Program Files\Scripts_Talend\SynchroExo_run.bat", "--context_param FileCode=ABCD --context_param FilePath=`"....."`

Answer (score 2):

Your string doesn't *contain* any quotes. It's just :

```
C:\Program Files\Scripts_Talend\SynchroExo_run.bat
```

When you concatenate that with the arguments you end up with a string that can't be executed.

In any case, you don't need to call `cmd.exe` to run any executable or batch, just pass the path as the argument to ... the executable. There's no need to use extra strings here because the parameter expects a path:

```
var batchPath="C:\Program Files\Scripts_Talend\SynchroExo_run.bat";
var arguments = "--context_param FileCode=ABCD --context_param FilePath=\"//networkname/Folder/file.xls\" --context_param ReportFilePath=\"\"";

var procInfo= new ProcessStartInfo(batchPath, arguments)
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
};
var scriptProcess= Process.Start(procInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the entire command string with a pair of \" made it work.

The final command string looks like that :

```
""C:\Program Files\Scripts_Talend\SynchroExo_run.bat" --context_param FileCode=ABCD --context_param FilePath="//networkname/Folder/file.xls" --context_param ReportFilePath="""
```

Comment: You simply covered up the problem. You don't need to use `cmd.exe` in the first place, just call the batch. Double quotes need *escaping* too. You missed the double quote in the arguments